# What's the meaning behind ZQN designation for the zombies in I Am A Hero?

Tags: japanese-language, i-am-a-hero

In the series *I Am a Hero* by Hanazawa Kengo, the designation for zombies was previously translated as "zombfags," presumably as an adaptation of the word for "normalfag," which if I'm not mistaken is 「リア[充]{じゅう}」.

However, the designation is currently translated (though it may have also remained unchanged from the original) as "ZQN," with no explanation given for the sudden change (I'm fairly certain I've come across an amalgamation of the work from at least two different translation groups).

My question is, does  the designation "ZQN" have roots in Japanese internet slang words, à la 「リア[充]{じゅう}」, or did earlier translations just take artistic liberty given the context?

Comment: There is a similar-looking piece of internet slang "DQN" / ドキュン _dokyun_ that means "someone who does dumb shit". I strongly suspect it is related (but I have no knowledge about _I Am A Hero_).

Comment: In context the name came from 2ch posts (the only surviving form of communication), so that seems pretty likely

Comment: Of course, as soon as I ask the question, the story explains it >_>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In chapter 220, it is explained that, officially, "ZQN" is an acronym made up by the US military that means "Zero Qualified Nucleus," though it is almost certainly a backronymic pun on the Japanese internet slang word "DQN" (pronounced *dokyun*):

> [ＤＱＮ]{ドキュン} (*Noun*)
>
> 1. dumb-ass (*slang, derogatory*)
> 2. delinquent; violent person; rough-looking person (*slang, derogatory*)
>
> > -adapted from [jisho.org](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%83%89%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A5%E3%83%B3)